# How to make a input in HTML in JS to integer

Tags: javascript, html

So I can not make the input into a integer. I want to turn this into a int so then it can calculate the age of you. I have been researching but can not find the right answer. 
HTML CODE:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>learn</title>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<form action="/learn.html">
    <b>Year Born:</b> <input id="input988744" type="value">
</form>
<button onClick="calculateAge(birthYear);">Summit</button>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript Code:

```
/*
Function
*/

// var
var birthYear;
birthYear = document.getElementById("input988744");

// function
function calculateAge(birthYearInFun) {
    "use strict";
    console.log(2018 - birthYearInFun); // make it a number
}
```

Comment: On what line? @Mirodinho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 things needs to be changed

1. HTML:Change type of `<input>` from `text` to `number`, number can be negative so can add parameter `min="1900"` to stop from entering date earlier then 1900

   ```
   <b>Year Born:</b> <input id="input988744" type="number" min="1900">
   ```
2. Javascript: Need to fetch value of HTML element, thus add `.value` adter `getElementById`, as `getElementById` gives HTML element not its value. To be on safer side use `parseInt()` or `Number()` over `birthYear`

   ```
   var birthYear;
   birthYear = Number(document.getElementById("input988744").value);
   or
   birthYear = parseInt(document.getElementById("input988744").value);
   ```

Both these will make birthYear number.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want it looks like is the input type to be a date... Check out the snippet below

```css
legend {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px 6px;
}

.output {
    font: 1rem 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}

input {
    margin: .4rem;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Choose trip dates</legend>

    <div>
        <label for="start">Start</label>
        <input type="date" id="start" name="trip"
               value="2018-07-22"
               min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="end">End</label>
        <input type="date" id="end" name="trip"
               value="2018-07-29"
               min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31"/ >
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the value of the input field as birthYearInFun.value as Mirodinho said and then if it a string, convert it to a number using parseInt().

`birthYear = parseInt(document.getElementById("input988744").value)`